# retag is broken, in that I can do it already

Tags: support, tags, edits

I just looked at my privileges, and I'm currently 86% of the way to having permission to retag questions. When I retag my first question, I'll get the Organizer bronze badge. Except, if you look at my profile, I already have that badge, because I've already retagged a question: [I added the flat-file tag to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/85/revisions)

It seems that when you click on edit, you can add and remove tags regardless of whether you have the retag privilege. If you're not supposed to be able to retag questions until you have that privilege, then tags should probably not be shown when editing a question.

Edit: Signing up for meta.stackoverflow.com gave me an additional 100 reputation on the site, so I now have that privilege legitimately, but at the time I performed the linked retag I did not have the privilege to do so. So looking at my account now will not reflect the state it was in when I performed the retag. Just so people don't get confused or think I'm trying to mislead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the description for the retag privilege, it allows you to retag a post without it going through the peer review system that edits go through.

> When you receive this privilege you get the ability to retag posts
>   without having to go through the peer review system. When you reach
>   2000 reputation, the retag button will disappear, since [all of your
>   edits will bypass the peer review
>   system](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit).

Comment: Then shouldn't I have also gotten the badge for editing a post more than 6 months old?

Comment: I am not sure about that badge, but some badge scripts run less often so it may take some time.

Comment: @DiMono [Excavator](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/1287/excavator) is for editing posts that were _inactive_ for 6 months. [The old question you edited](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85/flat-file-databases-in-php) was last active in January, when it received its newest answer. It's not immediately obvious what it means for a post to have activity, so it's understandable you misunderstood the requirements. Don't worry, some day you'll get the badge without even having noticed that the post was inactive long enough.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a bug.

When you get the ability to retag, it actually means that your retags won't have to be reviewed and as such will be committed.

On the other hand, when you edit a post, it is not made live immediately, but instead is flagged for review.

Further along the line you will also see an edit privilege, which again, means that you can edit without review.